# Dropdownlist Not Causing Async Postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a user control in my page (which is in a masterpage containing a scriptmanager tag) which contains two dropdownlists. The value of ddl1 (aka CatList) determines the content of ddl2 (aka CatList2). In the past I've done this using a full postback each time ddl1 is changed, but for a variety of reasons in this case I'd much rather it did a partial postback, however, I cannot seem to get the partial postback to work. My code, as it currently stands, is given below.

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.UI.UserControl" ClassName="KnownIssuesCode" %>
<%@ Import namespace="system.data" %>
<%@ Import namespace="system.data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">
Protected Dim ThePage as string
Sub Page_Load()
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      Dim myReader4 As IDataReader = CType(GetProduct.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), IDataReader)
        CatList.Items.Clear()
        CatList.DataValueField = "ProductID"
        CatList.DataTextField = "ProductName"
        CatList.DataSource=myReader4
        CatList.DataBind()
        CatList.SelectedValue = "0"
      myReader4.close
      If not isNothing(session("ProductID")) then
        CatList.SelectedValue = session("ProductID")
        ProductID.Text = session("ProductID")
      Else
        ProductID.Text = 0 
      End if
      Dim myReader2 As IDataReader = CType(GetModule.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), IDataReader)
        CatList2.Items.Clear()
        CatList2.DataValueField = "ModuleID"
        CatList2.DataTextField = "ModuleName"
        CatList2.DataSource=myReader2
        CatList2.DataBind()
        CatList2.SelectedValue = "0"
      myReader2.close
    End If
End Sub
Sub CatListIndex_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
  ProductID.Text = CatList.SelectedValue
  Dim myReader2 As IDataReader = CType(GetModule.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), IDataReader)
    CatList2.Items.Clear()
    CatList2.DataValueField = "ModuleID"
    CatList2.DataTextField = "ModuleName"
    CatList2.DataSource=myReader2
    CatList2.DataBind()
    CatList2.SelectedValue = "0"
  myReader2.close
End Sub
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  session("ProductID") = CatList.SelectedValue
  session("ModuleID") = CatList2.SelectedValue

  response.redirect("known-issues.aspx")
End Sub
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
   <div class="block-holder">
    <div class="block-frame">
      <div class="form-block">
        <h1>KNOWN ISSUES</h1>
        <div class="add-search-form">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <asp:dropdownlist title="PRODUCT" id="CatList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CatListIndex_Changed" AutoPostback="True" CssClass="size-3" runat="server" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <asp:dropdownlist id="CatList2" title="MODULE"  CssClass="standard" runat="server" />
              </div>
              <asp:Label ID="ProductID" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <span class="add-desc">FIND workarounds AND solutions</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GetModule" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX %>" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT ModuleID, ModuleName, ModuleSeq from Module where ModuleDeleted = 0 and (ProductID=@ProductID or ProductID=0) order by ModuleName" 
      DataSourceMode="DataReader">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ProductID" Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CatList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GetProduct" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX %>" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductSeq from Product order by ProductSeq"
  DataSourceMode="DataReader">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

eta:
At the moment, instead of doing a partial postback it's doing a full postback.

Comment: if you take out the update panel, does the postback word?

Comment: @Razvan: Yes. It does the same thing whether there's an update panel in or not. ie a full postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's turned out to be a security one, rather than a code one - I've tested my code on a different website and it works as intended.

After a bit of messing around with security settings, it turned out to be an issue with the wildcard filtering I'd got set up to prevent non .net pages to be accessed without being logged in. Taking that off solved the ajax issue and, at least for this site, the filtering was probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ChildrenAsTriggers="False"`,ChildrenAsTriggers="False" causes the UpdatePanel to  Postback on selected Trigger. You can find more info here [ChildrenAsTriggers](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/forums/updatepanel-childrenastriggers/p/1167/12744.aspx)

Comment: Err - why would I need to set autopostback="true" on CatList2? (which is what your code snippet says) CatList already has autopostback="true" set.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Just tried it and no change - still doing a full postback.

Comment: hmmm...could you check the Source Code of the rendered page,and check whether Script Manager source is rendered....it might be case that it is not getting randered...

Comment: @AmolKolekar might be right.. do you have a <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> at the top of the page?

Comment: I have just double checked; there is definitely a ScriptManager tag in my masterpage. I don't see it when I do a view source on the loaded page, but I'm not sure I'd expect to. (For comparison, I checked the source of another site where I've got similar functionality working and I don't see THAT scriptmanager tag either.)

Comment: @AmolKolekar I've now traced the problem to a "quirk" of the security I'd got set up on the site. I've adjusted the security and everything's now working fine. Many thank yous for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Sub CatListIndex_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

With

```
Protected Sub CatListIndex_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CatList.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Comment: Done that; unfortunately, no change in performance. Still doing a full postback.

Comment: what if you take out the EventName?

Comment: Still doing a full postback - sorry

Comment: I've now traced the problem to a "quirk" of the security I'd got set up on the site. I've adjusted the security and everything's now working fine. Many thank yous for your help!